# Decompose elements in $SL_2$ as a pair of elements in $SL_2^*$.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, poisson-geometry

I have a question about decomposing elements in $SL_2$ as a pair of elements in $SL_2^*$. Here $SL_2^*$ is the dual Poisson Lie group of $SL_2$ which is defined as follows.

Let $G$ be a Poisson-Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be the Killing form of on $\mathfrak{g}$. It is defined by
\begin{align*}
\langle x, y \rangle = \text{tr}(ad(x)ad(y)),
\end{align*}
where $x, y \in \mathfrak{g}$.

Let $\pi_{>0}$, $\pi_{<0}$ be projections of $\mathfrak{g}$ onto subalgebras spanned by positive and negative roots, $\pi_0$ be the projection onto the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$, and let $R = \pi_{>0} - \pi_{<0}$.

The double of $\mathfrak{g}$ is defined as $D(\mathfrak{g}) = \mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{g}$ which is equipped with an invariant non-degenerate bilinear form
\begin{align}
\langle \langle (\xi, \eta), (\xi', \eta') \rangle \rangle = \langle \xi, \xi' \rangle - \langle \eta, \eta' \rangle. \label{eq: bilinear form on Drinfeld double}
\end{align}
Define subalgebras $\mathfrak{d}_{\pm}$ of $D(\mathfrak{g})$ by $\mathfrak{d}_+ = \{ (\xi, \xi): \xi \in \mathfrak{g} \}$ and $\mathfrak{d}_- = \{ (R_+(\xi), R_-(\xi)): \xi \in \mathfrak{g} \}$, where $R_{\pm} \in \text{End}(\mathfrak{g})$ is given by $R_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(R \pm id)$. The Drinfeld double of $G$ is $D(G)=G \times G$.

The diagonal subgroup $\{(X,X): X \in G\}$ is a Poisson-Lie subgroup of $D(G)$ naturally isomorphic to $G$. The Lie algebra of $\{(X,X): X \in G\}$ is $\mathfrak{d}_+$.

The group $G^*$ whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{d}_-$ is a Poisson-Lie subgroup of $D(G)$ called the dual Poisson-Lie group of $G$.

In the case of $SL_2$, we have 
\begin{align*}
G=\{ \left( \left( \begin{matrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{matrix} \right), \left( \begin{matrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{matrix} \right) \right): a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}, ad-bc=1 \}
\end{align*}
\begin{align}
SL_2^*=G^* = \{ \left( \left( \begin{matrix}
x & y \\ 0 & x^{-1}
\end{matrix} \right), \left( \begin{matrix}
x^{-1} & 0 \\ z & x
\end{matrix} \right) \right): x \in \mathbb{C}^*, y, z \in \mathbb{C} \}.
\end{align}

Generic elements $x\in SL_2$ can be decomposed as $x=x_+\cdot x_-^{-1}$, $(x_+,x_-) \in SL_2^*$.

Let 
\begin{align*}
x = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ c & d \end{array}\right).
\end{align*}

The decomposition which satisfies $diag(x_+) \cdot diag(x_-) = 1$ and $x=x_+ \cdot x_-^{-1}$, $(x_+, x_-) \in SL_2^*$, is
\begin{align}
& x_+ = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} & \frac{b}{\sqrt{d}}\\ 0 & \sqrt{d} \end{array}\right),\\
& x_- = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{d} & 0\\ - \frac{c}{\sqrt{d}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \end{array}\right).
\end{align}
But there are elements in $x_+, x_-$ which involve the square root of $d$. Are there some mistakes in my computations? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe, 7.2 on page 33 of http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/lie-poi3.pdf can help.